# Why do I have to cast the delegate?

Tags: objective-c, properties, casting, compiler-warnings

I have a class and this class has a delegate protocol. I create an object in the main class using this class and assigned the main class as the delegate. The main class has a property I would like to read inside the created class. Then I do this:

```
BOOL prop = [self.delegate myProperty];
```

Xcode complains that "`delegate` may not respond to `myProperty`"

If I am sending a message to `self.delegate` to read `myProperty`, and generally Xcode never complains when you send a message to an not casted object, why do I have to do that

```
BOOL prop = [(myMainClass *)self.delegate myProperty];
```

to make it work?

To be more clear, here is an example of a message sent to an object without having to cast:

```
[self.myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){

    int Number = [[obj dictionaryOfNames] count];

}];
```

`self.myArray` is an array of objects from another class that are dictionaries and have this property `dictionaryOfNames`. Xcode never asked me to cast this:

```
int Number = [[(myOtherClass *)obj dictionaryOfNames] count];
```

as I had to above for `myProperty`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Different classes can conform to a protocol. If you declare that you conform to a protocol you just say that you will implement the requiered methods but you can implement it in a `UIView`, `UIViewController`, `MyOwnClass`, `MyOtherClass` etc.

Thats why a property is normally declared like this

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MyProtocol> delegate;
```

So you just say your delegate is an object which conform to the protocol.

Comment: Ok, but if I can send messages to objects using the format [obj message], why it is necessary to identify the object? Despite the delegate class, it should accept the format [obj message] without cheging, that as far as I know is the idea behind Objective-C... or not?

Comment: You can only send messages to objects which understand these messages otherwhise you'll get an error. Try to send some custom message to NSObject - it won't work.

Comment: sorry but this is not what I see. I have added some code to my question to explain.

Comment: Protocols specify methods, not properties. an object that conforms to a protocol coult in theory be of any class (the class is what specifies which properties an object has). You could add the property's getter/setter as protocol methods...

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown enough code to give a completely definitive answer, but in general terms I would expect that the definition of your delegate is *not* just id, you've probably used NSObject* or something similar.

The compiler is doing "static" analysis of your source code and trying to determine whether or not the object specified by "self.delegate" might implement that method.  If the data type is, say, NSObject*, then the compiler looks through that specific class definition to see if your method is present; if it isn't, then you'll get a *warning*.

If the data type of the message receiver is id, the compiler tends to give up and say "well, it could be anything so I'll assume this will work".

The result of the expression [obj dictionaryOfNames] is probably of type NSDictionary and the compiler can see that that particular class *does* respond to the count method.

Note, you can also get this problem if you have specified a class name for a property, but the compiler cannot see the entire class definition from this file.  For example, if you have

myobject.h:

```
@class Something;
@interface MyObject
@property (retain) Something *delegate;
@end
```

myobject.m:

```
#import "myobject.h"

[self.delegate doItYouFool];
```

then the compiler can see that the result of the expression 'self.delegate' is of type Something* but it can not see the actual definition of that class and thus can't look through its supported messages.  This usually results in a warning about 'forward definitions'.  To fix it, you should import "something.h" into the .m file, so that the compiler has full knowledge about the classes it is working with.  To just silence the warning, you cast to id

```
[(id)self.delegate doItYouFool];
```

You may, of course, also be getting warnings that 'doItYouFool' isn't a known method, again because you haven't included the header file that defines that message.